# PHP remove array if subarray empty

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

my array image just like this, if subarray "name" is empty or null i want delete array, how to do that ?

[image: here's my array]

here my current script

```
    $data       = array();
    $fixedData  = array();
    $countyName = array();
    $numrow = 2;
    echo "<pre>";
    // insert to tb participant => 1
    foreach($sheet as $key => $row){
    $data[] = array(
            'name' => $this->split_name($row['B']),
            'phone' => $row['D'],
            'mobile' => $row['E'],
            'institution' => $row['F'],
            'departement' => $row['G'],
            'address' => $row['H'],
            'country' => $row['I'],
    );

      $numrow++; 
    }
    unset($data[0]); //delete first row
    $data = array_values($data);

    //loop search data 

    var_dump ($data);
    die();
```

Comment: Have you tried `empty($data[0]['name'])`

Comment: here just deleted name subarray , not the parent array

Comment: do you have an already created array? or you want to avoid adding the null values in the creating phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have the following data set,

```
$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'not null', 'phone' => 12546
    ],[
        'name' => '', 'phone' => 852147
    ],[
        'name' => null, 'phone' => 96325874
    ],[
        'name' => 'have value', 'phone' => 12546
    ],
];
```

You can filter the nulled or empty values like several ways :

1-

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if (empty($value['name']) || is_null($value['name'])) {
        $value = null;
    }
}

$array = array_filter($array);
```

2-

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['name']) && !is_null($value['name'])) {
        $newData[] = $value;
    }
}
```

3- using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk)

```
$newData = [];
array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$newData) {
    if (!empty($value['name']) && !is_null($value['name'])) {
        $newData[] = $value;
    }
});
```

4- using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$newData = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    if (!empty($value['name']) && !is_null($value['name'])) {
        return $value;
    }
});
```

Comment: here my array sir, https://postimg.cc/image/kstaxmhy3/, i want if array named as "name" if "" or null the parent array is removed ... how to do that ?

Comment: have you tried any of my posted solutions? that what is already happens

Comment: not working sir :( , https://pastebin.com/raw/GYDzGvfC it's still show 645 arrays , it's should be just 381 arrays ...

Comment: can you send a json encoded array? I can not reproduce the dumped array at all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data       = array();
$fixedData  = array();
$countyName = array();
$numrow = 2;
echo "<pre>";
// insert to tb participant => 1
foreach($sheet as $key => $row){

    if($this->split_name($row['B'])!=='' && $this->split_name($row['B'])!==NULL){
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $this->split_name($row['B']),
            'phone' => $row['D'],
            'mobile' => $row['E'],
            'institution' => $row['F'],
            'departement' => $row['G'],
            'address' => $row['H'],
            'country' => $row['I'],
        );
        $numrow++;
    }

}



//loop search data

var_dump ($data);
die();
```

I simple put an if condition inside your loop so you can check if your value is null or empty and if it is then you don't fill your new array. Also moved your counter inside the if so you increment it only in a success array push

A more "elegant" way for your if condition is this as well:

```
if (!empty($this->split_name($row['B'])) && !is_null($this->split_name($row['B'])))
```

Comment: not working sir, can u check my full script on pastebin ? here it's https://pastebin.com/wULeq4hJ

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what's not working? Your `$data` array should have only the nested array which have a value in the `name` field.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/image/kstaxmhy3/ if array name empty like this i want remove them sir, but it's still displaying

Comment: print_r your array and provide us with a sample of your data to reproduce the problem. Not in an image format please.